# Based on Zephaniah 3:9 & John 14:14, what Name should All peoples be calling & serving : "Yehovah" or "Iésous"?

Tags: john, prophecy, messiah, names-of-god, zephaniah

**If Zephaniah 3:9 is about Converts calling God's Name in pure speech (with Honesty) & serving God in His Name - What is [the] שֵׁם Shem of God declared by His prophet צְפַנְיָה֙ Tsefaniah?**

> [Tsefaniah | Zephaniah 3:9]
> "For then I will convert the peoples to a [pure speech] that [all of them] call In [the]-Name of [YHVH], to serve Him of [one] accord." (כִּי־אָ֛ז אֶהְפֹּ֥ךְ אֶל־עַמִּ֖ים שָׂפָ֣ה בְרוּרָ֑ה לִקְרֹ֚א כֻלָּם֙ בְּשֵׁ֣ם יְהֹוָ֔ה לְעָבְד֖וֹ שְׁכֶ֥ם אֶחָֽד)

- Li-Qro לִקְרֹ֚א = "To-Call"
- Kul-am כֻלָּם֙ = "All-[of]-Them"
- Be-Shem בְּשֵׁ֣ם = "In-[the]-Name"
- YHVH יְהֹוָ֔ה (Yih**Ye**,**Hov**eh,Hay**ah**) = "Ye-HoV-aH"

**Instead of fulfilling the prophecy of Zephaniah 3:9 for the messianic age calling on pure Name YHVH יְהֹוָ֔ה , we are told in the Gospel of John to call on a different name : Ἰησοῦς "Iésous" in John 14:14.**

[John 14:14] - “If you ask anything in My name, I will do it. (14:14  ἐάν τι αἰτήσητέ ἐν τῷ ὀνόματί μου ἐγὼ ποιήσω)

In the Gospel of John, honest worship would be considered calling on & serving in the Greek name : Ἰησοῦς "Iésous" , instead of the Ivri Name : "Yehovah" יְהֹוָ֔ה .

- Yehovah יְהֹוָ֔ה is not a transliterated variant of Yehoshua יְהוֹשֻׁעַ > Yeshua יֵשׁ֨וּעַ > Joshua > Iésous Ἰησοῦς > Jesus... so which Name should All peoples Call on & Serve?

**Based on Zephaniah 3:9 & John 14:14, what Name should All peoples be calling & serving : "Yehovah" or "Iésous"?**

Comment: It's probably "Yahweh", not "Yehovah". The vowel-marks you listed for the Tetragrammaton aren't meant to actually be pronounced like that; they're reminders that you should replace it with the word "Adonai", and consist of the vowel markers for that replacement word instead. Scholarly consensus is that the actual pronunciation was likely something more like "Yahweh".

Answer (score 5):

This might be a different direction that you were asking (sorry if I misread)

Part of the distinction you are seeing is an important change between the Old and New Covenants with the relationship of the Covenant Creator and the people with whom He covenants. In the covenant of Moses and Israel, God reveals for the first time His name (YHWH), and permits these people to use that name when they reach out to Him (ex. 3:16).

Yet there is an important point of the new covenant: that name is never, not even once, directly used. Instead, there is a new covenant term that becomes the norm: Father (Matthew 6:9).

It is remarkable to contrast the absence of use of "Father" in the relationship of God and Israel in the covenant of Moses (I believe only five times, once the prophetic uses are removed), and the absence of a direct use of YHWH/Jehovah in the New Covenant. As the writer of the book of Hebrews points out, this is why the covenant of Christ is a better covenant

Hebrews 8:6 *But now He has obtained a more excellent ministry, inasmuch as He is also Mediator of a better covenant, which was established on better promises*.

The covenant of Moses permitted men to call on God by His name, indicating His friendship. The covenant of Christ permits men to call God Father, indicating the adoption of grace (Galatians 4:5, Ephesians 1:5).

Comment: Then Zephaniah 3:9 would only be considered a prophecy to humans under "the covenant of Moses" (as you have stated). - Correct?

Comment: Good question. What I might say is that "Calling on the Name of the Lord" in the Covenant of Christ is not literally using that covenant of Moses name (YHWH). Instead, it is described as being obedient. Peter references this in Acts 2:21, and Paul states how it is done here: Act 22:16 "And now why are you waiting? Arise and be baptized, and wash away your sins, calling on the name of the Lord." Does this make sense? Calling on the name of the Lord in the covenant of Christ is not about using the name YHWH, it is about being obedient to the law of Christ.

Comment: Exactly. - If as you say : "Calling on the Name of the Lord [in the Covenant of Christ] is not literally using that covenant of Moses name (YHWH)", then Zephaniah 3:9 should no longer be considered a prophecy by humans  [in the Covenant of Christ] since it will never be fulfilled.

Comment: Thanks - maybe it is worth considering that (1) calling on the name of the Lord even in the Torah did not always mean using the name YHWH (as in Genesis 4:26), and (2) there are other prophecies in the covenant of Moses with the exact same wording (Joel 2:32) that are specifically identified as referring to the covenant of Christ (Acts 2:21).

Answer (score 3):

A name is a written or verbal denotation of a person.
The person here is the Almighty Creator God.

Let's say "Iésous" denotes this person. English people use a different notation: "Jesus"; Chinese: "耶穌"; etc. There is no unique notation for this unique person.

Now, let's say "Yehovah" denotes this person. Some argue that it should be "Yahweh"; etc.
Again, there is no unique notation for this unique person.

In either case, there is no unique notation for this unique person.

Zephaniah 3:

> 9
> “Then I will purify the lips of the peoples, that all of them may call on **the name of the LORD** and serve him shoulder to shoulder.

John 14:

> 14
> You may ask me for anything **in my name**, and I will do it.

Which name should we use?

Use a name that is commanded in the Bible that means the Almighty Creator God to you.
Further, as long as your heart sincerely seeks the One True God, I don't think God would get offended by you for mispronouncing his name. No one knows how to pronounce it properly 100% :)

1 Samuel 16:

> 7c People look at the outward appearance, but the LORD looks at the heart.

OP: If God does not care what Name He is called : Why would His Word speak through Zephaniah that all peoples in one accord call a specific Name?

God does care about what Name He is called. When Zephaniah was written, יְהוָ֔ה identified the Almighty Creator God. God did not want people to call him e.g., baal.
At the same time, a person could call him יְהוָ֔ה insincerely and used the name in vain.

OP: Why would the Word of God not mention that all peoples can pray to whatever name they want as long as their title is associated with only one Supreme Creator?

Because God cares about what name people call him by. The name of God is sacred.

OP: Why does Ἰησοῦς not mention that all peoples can call on any name they choose as long as their title refers to the Supreme Creator's intercessory Son?

Because not any superficial name would do. The name of God is sacred.

Comment: If God does not care what Name He is called : Why would His Word speak through Zephaniah that all peoples in one accord call a specific Name? -- Why would the Word of God not mention that all peoples can pray to whatever name they want as long as their title is associated with only one Supreme Creator? -- Why does Ἰησοῦς not mention that all peoples can call on any name they choose as long as their title refers to the Supreme Creator's intercessory Son? -- Which is it?

Comment: Good questions. I clarified :)

Answer (score 1):

In Hebrew, God's name is and always has been "Yehovah" (I prefer spelling it as "Jehovah").  In Greek, the name of the Son of Man, the Messiah in whom the Father dwelt, is "Jesus (Christ)."

Jesus said:

> I am come in my Father's name, and ye receive me not: if another shall
> come in his own name, him ye will receive. (John 5:43, KJV)

So Jesus has come in the Father's name; and we are told to address the Father in Jesus' name.

> And whatsoever ye do in word or deed, do all in the name of the Lord
> Jesus, giving thanks to God and the Father by him.  (Colossians 3:17,
> KJV)

Jesus taught that we should pray to the Father in his name (Jesus).

> Ye have not chosen me, but I have chosen you, and ordained you, that
> ye should go and bring forth fruit, and that your fruit should remain:
> that whatsoever ye shall ask of the Father in my name, he may give it
> you. (John 15:16, KJV)
>
> And in that day ye shall ask me nothing. Verily, verily, I say unto
> you, Whatsoever ye shall ask the Father in my name, he will give it
> you. (John 16:23, KJV)

God's people are to be called by His name.

> If my people, which are called by my name, shall humble themselves,
> and pray, and seek my face, and turn from their wicked ways; then will
> I hear from heaven, and will forgive their sin, and will heal their
> land. (2 Chronicles 7:14, KJV)

And what name do God's people go by today?  Is it not "Christians," linking them to "Christ" (the anointed one)?

Indeed, the name of Jesus Christ, according to the Bible, is the only name by which we may be saved.

> Be it known unto you all, and to all the people of Israel, that **by the
> name of Jesus Christ** of Nazareth, whom ye crucified, whom God raised
> from the dead, even by him doth this man stand here before you whole.
> (Acts 4:10, KJV)
>
> Neither is there salvation in any other: for there is none other name
> under heaven given among men, whereby we must be saved. (Acts 4:12,
> KJV)

**Conclusion**

God is honored through the name of Christ Jesus our Lord.

> That the name of our Lord Jesus Christ may be glorified in you, and ye
> in him, according to the grace of our God and the Lord Jesus Christ.
> (2 Thessalonians 1:12, KJV)

Comment: "In Hebrew, God's name is and always has been "Yehovah" (I prefer spelling it as "Jehovah")." IIRC "Jehovah" was an invention of an American scholar who interpreted Hebrew texts overly literally. It was most likely never "Yehovah" or "Jehovah" up until then.

Comment: @nick012000 Jews have not pronounced the name for thousands of years--to the point that no one actually knows its original pronunciation.  Vowel pointings were added by the Masoretes well after Christ's time, and they deliberately added the vowels for "Adonai" to the tetragrammaton--as that is what they usually say in its place.  In my Hebrew classes, however, one astute student asked the professor about a pronunciation that was probably nearest the original, and the professor concurred.  It was something like "Yi-he-yay."  Words aren't always pronounced the same in other languages, though.

Answer (score 1):

Yeshua (Iesous) means YHVH's Savior .
Praying is essentially to call upon.
We call upon THE LORD (YHVH), and we can be named by The Lord.
Or to carry His name.

> Matthew 6:9-13 (kjv)
>
> 9 After this manner therefore pray ye: Our Father  which art in
> heaven, Hallowed be thy name.
>
> 10 Thy kingdom come, Thy will be done in earth, as it is in heaven.

Christ always said pray to The Heavenly Father.

After Jesus resurrected faithful were to be called by a New Name.

> Isaiah 62:2  And the Gentiles shall see thy righteousness, and all
> kings thy glory: and thou shalt be called by a new name, which the
> mouth of the LORD shall name.

Israel wasn't to be remembered by her old name

> Hosea 2:17   For I will take away the names of Baalim out of her
> mouth, and they shall no more be remembered by their name.

Their new name is The Lords Name:

> 2  Chronicles 7:14    If my people, which are called by my name, shall
> humble themselves, and pray, and seek my face, and turn from their
> wicked ways; then will I hear from heaven, and will forgive their sin,
> and will heal their land.

Christians ; disciple of Christ is that Name.

> 1 Peter 4:16  Yet if any man suffer as a Christian, let him not be
> ashamed; but let him glorify God on this behalf.
>
> John 13:35  By this shall all men know that ye are my disciples, if ye
> have love one to another.
>
> Act 11:26  And when he had found him, he brought him unto Antioch. And
> it came to pass, that a whole year they assembled themselves with the
> church, and taught much people. And the disciples were called
> Christians first in Antioch.

We know Christ is God in the flesh because if you've seen The Son you've seen The Father. So they're one in the same. But as Jesus said to do we pray to  YHVH and in Christs name we speak or pray.

> John 14:13-14 (kjv)
>
> 13 And whatsoever ye shall ask in my name, that will I do, that the
> Father may be glorified in the Son.
>
> 14 If ye shall ask any thing in my name, I will do it.

Answer (score 1):

This "problem" is not unique to Zeph 3:9 where people are told to use the name of יְהוָ֔ה YHWH/Jehovah, etc.

- Heb 1:6 quotes the LXX of Deut 32:43 about YHWH and applies it to Jesus
- Heb 1:8, 9 quotes Ps 45:6, 7 about YHWH and applies it to Jesus
- Heb 1:10-12 quotes the LXX of Ps 102:25-27 about YHWH and applies it to Jesus
- Phil 2:10, 11 quotes Isa 45:23 about YHWH and applies it to Jesus
- Matt 3:3 (cf V11) quotes Isa 40:3 about YHWH and applies it to Jesus
- Rom 10:13 quotes Joel 2:32 about YHWH and applies it to Jesus

This is part of very general patter in the NT that takes unique aspects of YHWH on the OT and applies them to Jesus - see appendix below.

Thus, the NT recognizes Jesus as Jehovah.

**APPENDIX - OT unique aspects of YHWH applied to Jesus in the NT**

| Old Testament Title/Quality of YHWH | NT applies to Jesus |
| --- | --- |
| Creator Isa 44:24, 45:18 | John 1:3, 10, Col 1:16, 17, Heb 1:2 |
| Saviour Isa 43:3, 11, 45:17, 21 | Matt 1:21; Acts 4:12; 2 Tim 1:10; Tit 1:4, 2:13, 3:6; 2 Pet 1:1, 11 |
| Glory Isa 42:8, 48:11 | John 17:5, 24 |
| Rock Isa 44:8; Deut 32:3,4,15; Ps 92:15 | 1 Cor 10:4; Matt 16:18 |
| Shepherd Psalm 23:1; Eze 34:11ff | John 10:11-16; Heb 13:20; 1 Peter 2:25, 5:4; Rev 7:17 |
| Bridegroom Isa 49, 54, Jer 2, Hosea | Mark 2:19, Matt 9:15, Luke 5:34, 35 |
| First & Last Isa 41:4, 44:6, 48:12 | Rev 1:17, 18, 2:8, 22:13 |
| Angels Job 4:18, Ps 91:11, 103:20 | Matt 13:41, 24:31, Mark 13:27 |
| Venerable Ex 20:3, 34:14; Deut 8:19; 2 Kings 17:35-38 | Matt 2:11, 14:33, 28:9, 17; Luke 4:8; 24:52; John 9:38, Rom 10:9, Heb 1:5, 6, Phil 2:10, Rev 5:6-12 |
| Light Ps 27:1, Micah 7:8 | John 1:9, 8:12, 9:5, 1 John 1:5-7 |
| Search hearts and minds Jer 11:20, 17:10, 1 Sam 16:7 | Rev 2:23 |
| Lord of Lords Deut 10:17, Ps 136:3, 26 | Rev 17:14, 19:16 |
| Lord of All | Deut 10:17, Josh 3:11, 13' Ps 97:5, Zech 4:14, 6:5, Mic 4:13 |
| Seven Eyes of the LORD Zech 4:10 (& Zech 3:9) | Rev 5:6 (Lamb) |

This list is not exhaustive